# Phonegap file transfer using ashx http handler - files are not found on server

Tags: android, cordova, file-upload, ihttphandler

I'm trying to upload an image to a remote server using Phonegap's (3.4.0) file transfer and an ashx http handler. I'm using eclipse and running the app on a galaxy s3 device.
here's my code:

js:

```
function updateUserImage(userId,imageURI) {
    //imageURI is in the format of file:///...
    alert("in update()");
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, onResolveSuccess, fail);
}

function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {

    var options = new FileUploadOptions(); // PhoneGap object to allow server upload
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = "1000.jpg";
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg"; // file type
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        var params = {};
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";
        options.params = params;
        options.headers = {
            Connection: "close"
        };

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    alert("resolve success");
    alert(fileEntry.toURL());
    ft.upload(fileEntry.toURL(), encodeURI("http://www.xxxx.com/ReturnValue.ashx"), win, fail, options, true); // Upload
}
function win(r) {
    alert("win");
    alert(r.response);
}
```

ashx:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ReturnValue" %>

 using System;
 using System.Web;

public class ReturnValue : IHttpHandler
{

     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {
         context.Response.Write(context.Request.Files.Count);
     }

     public bool IsReusable
     {
          get
          {
               return false;
          }
     }

}
```

logcat:

```
05-14 17:56:01.834: V/webview(2125):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
05-14 17:56:02.224: W/PluginManager(2125): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Camera.takePicture blocked the main thread for 56ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
05-14 17:56:02.224: D/CordovaActivity(2125): Paused the application!
05-14 17:56:02.224: D/CordovaWebView(2125): Handle the pause
05-14 17:56:02.819: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2125): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-14 17:56:08.274: D/CordovaActivity(2125): Incoming Result
05-14 17:56:08.274: D/CordovaActivity(2125): Request code = 34
05-14 17:56:08.274: D/CordovaActivity(2125): We have a callback to send this result to
05-14 17:56:08.314: D/dalvikvm(2125): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 841K, 11% free 12366K/13831K, paused 16ms, total 24ms
05-14 17:56:08.379: I/dalvikvm-heap(2125): Grow heap (frag case) to 43.056MB for 31961104-byte allocation
05-14 17:56:08.394: D/dalvikvm(2125): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 4% free 43571K/45063K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
05-14 17:56:08.394: W/CursorWrapperInner(2125): Cursor finalized without prior close()
05-14 17:56:08.409: D/dalvikvm(2125): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 43571K/45063K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 16ms
05-14 17:56:10.139: D/dalvikvm(2125): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
05-14 17:56:10.169: D/dalvikvm(2125): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31267K, 73% free 12321K/45063K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 30ms
05-14 17:56:10.169: E/System(2125): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125): java.io.IOException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125):     at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:41)
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125):     at java.io.FileInputStream.close(FileInputStream.java:121)
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125):     at java.io.FileInputStream.finalize(FileInputStream.java:142)
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:186)
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125):     at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125):     at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:38)
05-14 17:56:10.174: E/System(2125):     ... 5 more
05-14 17:56:10.174: W/CursorWrapperInner(2125): Cursor finalized without prior close()
05-14 17:56:10.174: I/CordovaLog(2125): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
05-14 17:56:10.179: D/Whitelist(2125): Unlimited access to network resources
05-14 17:56:10.179: D/CordovaActivity(2125): Resuming the App
05-14 17:56:10.179: D/CordovaActivity(2125): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
05-14 17:56:10.234: D/CordovaLog(2125): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 23 : file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.phonegap.helloworld/cache/1400079368295.jpg
05-14 17:56:10.234: I/Web Console(2125): file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.phonegap.helloworld/cache/1400079368295.jpg:23
05-14 17:56:10.289: D/dalvikvm(2125): GC_CONCURRENT freed 42K, 72% free 12737K/45063K, paused 2ms+13ms, total 28ms
05-14 17:56:10.304: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(2125): Ignore this event
05-14 17:56:10.454: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(2125): Ignore this event
05-14 17:56:16.739: D/FileTransfer(2125): upload file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.phonegap.helloworld/cache/1400079368295.jpg to http://www.xxxx.com/ReturnValue.ashx
05-14 17:56:16.739: D/FileTransfer(2125): fileKey: file
05-14 17:56:16.739: D/FileTransfer(2125): fileName: 1000.jpg
05-14 17:56:16.739: D/FileTransfer(2125): mimeType: image/jpeg
05-14 17:56:16.739: D/FileTransfer(2125): params: {"value1":"test","value2":"param"}
05-14 17:56:16.739: D/FileTransfer(2125): trustEveryone: true
05-14 17:56:16.739: D/FileTransfer(2125): chunkedMode: false
05-14 17:56:16.739: D/FileTransfer(2125): headers: {"Connection":"close"}
05-14 17:56:16.739: D/FileTransfer(2125): objectId: 1
05-14 17:56:16.739: D/FileTransfer(2125): httpMethod: POST
05-14 17:56:16.764: D/FileTransfer(2125): Content Length: 358920
05-14 17:56:34.384: D/dalvikvm(2125): GC_CONCURRENT freed 150K, 72% free 12974K/45063K, paused 8ms+5ms, total 47ms
05-14 17:56:58.089: D/FileTransfer(2125): Uploaded 114920 of 358920 bytes
05-14 17:57:15.299: D/FileTransfer(2125): Uploaded 229608 of 358920 bytes
05-14 17:57:17.069: D/FileTransfer(2125): Uploaded 344296 of 358920 bytes
05-14 17:57:17.704: D/FileTransfer(2125): Sent 358920 of 358920
05-14 17:57:22.229: D/FileTransfer(2125): response code: 200
05-14 17:57:22.234: D/FileTransfer(2125): response headers: {null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Cache-Control=[private], Connection=[close], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=utf-8], Date=[Wed, 14 May 2014 14:57:33 GMT], OkHttp-Received-Millis=[1400079442236], OkHttp-Response-Source=[NETWORK 200], OkHttp-Selected-Transport=[http/1.1], OkHttp-Sent-Millis=[1400079441802], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/8.0], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], X-Powered-By-Plesk=[PleskWin]}
05-14 17:57:22.239: D/FileTransfer(2125): got response from server
05-14 17:57:22.239: D/FileTransfer(2125): 0
05-14 17:57:22.334: D/dalvikvm(2125): GC_CONCURRENT freed 778K, 72% free 12691K/45063K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 29ms
05-14 17:
```

my config.xml has `<access origin="*"/>` in it, and manifest file has `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`.

I get a response "0" from the server, which means it didn't get any of the files. But on the other hand, logcat says "Sent 358920 of 358920".

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.